# Getting "This method or property cannot be called on Null values" error

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, c#-3.0, asmx, asp.net-3.5

**UPDATE 1:**

The exception is being thrown on this line:

```
client_group_details.Add(new ClientGroupDetails(
```

**ORIGINAL QUESTION:**

I have the following code which I have stripped down from 30 columns of data from the database to just 2 columns from the database.  I get an error whenever any of the columns return a NULL value:

```
public class ClientGroupDetails
{
    public String Col2;
    public String Col3;

    public ClientGroupDetails(String m_Col2, String m_Col3)
    {
        Col2 = m_Col2;
        Col3 = m_Col3;
    }

    public ClientGroupDetails() { }
}

[WebMethod()]
public List<ClientGroupDetails> GetClientGroupDetails(string phrase)
{
    var client_group_details = new List<ClientGroupDetails>();

    using (connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connString"]))
    {
        using (command = new SqlCommand(@"select col2, col3 where col1 = @phrase", connection))
        {
            command.Parameters.Add("@phrase", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = phrase;

            connection.Open();
            using (reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                int Col2Index = reader.GetOrdinal("col2");
                int Col3Index = reader.GetOrdinal("col3");

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    client_group_details.Add(new ClientGroupDetails(
                        reader.GetString(Col2Index),
                        reader.GetString(Col3Index)));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return client_group_details;
}
```

The error I am getting is:

Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values.

I'm not sure what to do here to deal with NULL values as the code above is a stripped down version.

Anyone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: Which line of your code is causing the exception to be thrown?  And what is the class of the exception (e.g. `ArgumentNullException`)?

Comment: It seems that you aren't the first person to get this kind of exception and post about it.  Somebody found this kind of issue when working with TFS, and the concrete exception type was `SqlNullValueException` (see http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsversioncontrol/thread/c7ee4549-eea6-4536-9f9b-bcfce2b1e404).

Comment: This is not a `NULL` in the database sense. It's a `null` meaning the reference has no value. What is the exact exception you're seeing? `ArgumentNullException`?

Comment: I'm getting the exception on `client_group_details.Add(new ClientGroupDetails(`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because `reader.GetString` should not be called on `DBNull` values. Try changing your code as follows:

```
client_group_details.Add(new ClientGroupDetails(
    reader.IsDbNull(Col2Index) ? null : reader.GetString(Col2Index),
    reader.IsDbNull(Col3Index) ? null : reader.GetString(Col3Index)));
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to read some nullable data from the database, but your type is not nullable you can get this error.

If MyInt is nullable in the database and you have this entity:

```
public class MyEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int MyInt { get; set; }
}
```

You will get the exception: System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException: 'Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values.'

To fix this, just change the type of your MyInt property to Nullable or int?:

```
public class MyEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? MyInt { get; set; }
}
```

Note: This is not an answer to the original question, but is an answer to the question in the title.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use IsDbNull to check if the column is null before calling [GetString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getstring.aspx), something like:

```
string s1, s2;

if (reader.IsDbNull(Col1Index) == false)
{
   s1 = reader.GetString(Col1Index);
}

if (reader.IsDbNull(Col2Index) == false)
{
   s2 = reader.GetString(Col2Index);
}

client_group_details.Add(new ClientGroupDetails(s1, s2));
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways you can do this, but I think the best approach for your code is to add a simple function call to your SQL text - namely, the `IsNull` function.

Here's a link to the manual page for this: [IsNull MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx)

Basically, you'll change your SQL text to look similar to this:

```
"select IsNull(col2, ''), IsNull(col3, '') where col1 = @phrase"
```

And now if the column in the DB is null, it will instead return a blank string.

You can also set default values on your columns, or you can check for `System.DBNull.Value` on your code side.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I am hoping this helps:

When adding new columns to my existing table if it is a bit column (boolean) I set the default value in SQL Server 2019 to "(0)" (false), and made the column Nullable.

I guess when making a column nullable, and having a default value, the default value will not be added when creating a new row without explicitly referencing the column in the INSERT SQL.

Since the error never specifies a column name which can really cross your eyes in a big table, I just open the latest rows and look for bit columns that have Null values. Then I change my code to explicitly add "0" to that column when creating a new row. And manually change the offending columns. (might be a little tougher on a lot of rows).

That is one solution but ideal solution is go to back and make the column definition "Not Null".

There is also a solution probably of changing the Model in my .NET Core 2.2 Razor Pages app.