# Getting "no implicit conversion between '<null>' and 'System.DateTime'" error message

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, c#-3.0, asmx, asp.net-3.5

In a previous question:

[Getting "This method or property cannot be called on Null values" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9397960/getting-this-method-or-property-cannot-be-called-on-null-values-error)

I had a problem with the following code:

```
client_group_details.Add(new ClientGroupDetails(
    reader.GetString(Col2Index),
    reader.GetString(Col3Index)));
```

Where I was getting the following error:

```
Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values.
```

This problem was resolved using the following code:

```
client_group_details.Add(new ClientGroupDetails(
    reader.IsDbNull(Col2Index) ? null : reader.GetString(Col2Index),
    reader.IsDbNull(Col3Index) ? null : reader.GetString(Col3Index)));
```

I now have a similar problem with `GetDateTime` and `GetInt32`, as example is:

```
client_group_details.Add(new ClientGroupDetails(
    reader.GetString(Col2Index),
    reader.GetString(Col3Index),
    reader.GetDateTime(Col4Index)));
```

I tried using the following to resolve this problem, but it didn't work

```
client_group_details.Add(new ClientGroupDetails(
    reader.IsDbNull(Col2Index) ? null : reader.GetString(Col2Index),
    reader.IsDbNull(Col3Index) ? null : reader.GetString(Col3Index),
    reader.IsDbNull(Col2Index) ? null : reader.GetDateTime(Col4Index)));
```

It gives the error:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS0173: Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between '<null>' and 'System.DateTime'
```

After searching for a solution, I found: [Nullable type issue with ?: Conditional Operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295833/nullable-type-issue-with-conditional-operator).  But when I try to use that code, I keep getting `) expected`.

How would I resolve this problem?

Comment: Count your parens. You have more left parens than right parens.

Comment: Post the code that you tried to use that caused the `) expected` error.  That's a simple syntax error that should be easy to fix.

Comment: Thanks to John Saunders for pointing out I missed the point entirely. Answer deleted.

Comment: 20 hours and still no sign of the code with the actual problem with the parenthesis. Closing as too not a real question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are missing a closing bracket somewhere.

```
client_group_details.Add(new ClientGroupDetails(
    reader.IsDbNull(Col2Index) ? null : reader.GetString(Col2Index),
    reader.IsDbNull(Col3Index) ? null : reader.GetString(Col3Index),
    reader.IsDbNull(Col2Index) ? null : reader.GetDateTime(Col4Index)));
```

Should probably change to

```
client_group_details.Add(new ClientGroupDetails(
    reader.IsDbNull(Col2Index) ? null : reader.GetString(Col2Index),
    reader.IsDbNull(Col3Index) ? null : reader.GetString(Col3Index),
    reader.IsDbNull(Col2Index) ? (DateTime?)null : reader.GetDateTime(Col4Index)));
```

or something similar. Depending on your exact code someone will be able to tell you where the missing bracket it.

Answer (score 9):

`DateTime` is a `struct` and therefore a value type and cannot be `null`. Only reference types and `Nullable<T>` (or `T?`) types can be null. You have to use a `Nullable<DateTime>`. This can also be written as `DateTime?`.

```
DateTime? dt = null;
dt = DateTime.Now;
if (dt.HasValue) ...
if (dt == null) ...
DateTime x = dt.Value;

dt = reader.IsDBNull(Col2Index) ? (DateTime?)null : reader.GetDateTime(Col4Index);
```

Comment: That's what I've been trying, but I keep getting `) expected`.

Comment: Try to use `reader.IsDBNull(Col2Index) ? (DateTime?)null : reader.GetDateTime(Col4Index)`. The ternary operator is confused, beacause it cannot determine the type of `null`.

Comment: You have a syntax error somewhere. You have more `(` than `)`. Try adding a `)` at the end.

Comment: @oshirowanen **post the code that raises the `) expected` error.**  Adding `)` at the end may or may not fix the problem.